# backScalingFactor on Retina display not showing 2.0

Tags: objective-c, macos

Here's the code I'm using to get the backing scale factor from the window:

```
GCFloat backingScaleFactor = [[NSScreen mainScreen] backingScaleFactor];
NSLog(@"scale factor %.2f", backingScaleFactor);
```

And I also have this in the info.plist:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

I've tried putting different variations of the above in the info.plist also, like these:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>True<string>
```

and

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>true<string>
```

I still don't get the correct backingScaleFactor, even though I'm on a Retina display. I have another app that does give me 2.0 for the backingScaleFactor, so I'm wondering if there is anything else I'm missing?

Comment: By the way, how about the various `convertToBacking` methods (which are preferable anyway) for the `NSView`? Do those show the incorrect values, too?

Comment: BTW, if you did have to add to plist, it is `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key><true/>`. By the way, make sure the "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox is not marked in the "Get Info" screen for your executable. Or you can disable that entirely by adding `<key>NSHighResolutionMagnifyAllowed</key><false/>` to your plist.

Comment: All I did was do a clean build a everything worked fine (I deleted my build folder and rebuilt).

And to be clear, I tested getting the NSHighResolution value to make sure it was actually being read. So I'm not sure what the problem was :/

Comment: When I just tested it, if "Open in Low Resolution" selected in Finder, it doesn't matter whether you have `NSHighResolutionCapable` on or not. I had to explicitly uncheck that "Open in Low Resolution" option or set `NSHighResolutionMagnifyAllowed` to `false`. But I'm glad your fix was so simple.